# Multiple linked Django forms, one submit

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have models for Application and Role. Role is linked to a FK Role_type, which is linked by FK to Applications that can use those Role_types (this is a bit of an over-simplication for the question, but I think it suffices).  I need a way to create a form to make a new Application, and also to create records assigning associated roles to people (although they can be left blank.)

I have gotten as far as creating the form for the Application and having the associated Role-Types appear on the page, with dropdowns to be populated with a user.  Hitting submit, though, didn't create any of the associated Role records.  All of my research seems to keep coming back to Inline Model Forms, but the docs aren't really making sense to me--the inputs in the example don't seem to correlate to what I need.

I know this may seem like a duplicate, but trust me when I say I've looked at every SO question that seems to relate to this!

EDIT:  My POST looks like this:  `QueryDict: {u'roles-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], u'roles-1-role_type': [u'4'], u'roles-0-user': [u'1'], u'app-owner': [u'1'], u'app-name': [u'1234'], u'app-serviceTier': [u''], u'app-jiraProject': [u''], u'roles-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2'], u'roles-1-user': [u''], u'roles-0-role_type': [u'3'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'eGsDwtsSQJfl0'], u'roles-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'2']}>`.  Printing RolesFormSet gives me the exact same output (see comment below)

models.py

```
class Item(models.model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=255)  
    roles   = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Role')

class Application(Item):
    other_assorted_attributes = foo

class RoleType(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ItemTypeRoleMapping(models.Model):
''' pairs role-types (e.g., Developer) with an Item class they are relevant to'''
    roleType    = models.ForeignKey(RoleType)
    itemType    = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=itemChoices)        

class Role(models.Model):
    role_type   = models.ForeignKey(RoleType)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item        = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

views.py

```
def buildRolesFormset(itemClass):
    ''' given an item, build a form for all associated roles '''
    roleTypesForItem = ItemTypeRoleMapping.objects.all().filter(itemType=itemClass.__name__)
    applicable_roles = [{'role_type': roleType} for roleType in roleTypesForItem]
    # formset = rolesFormSet(initial=initial, prefix='roles')
    RoleFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Application, Role, extra=len(roleTypesForItem), can_delete=False)
    formset = RoleFormSet()
    for subform, data in zip(formset.forms, applicable_roles):
        subform.initial = data
    return formset

def new(request):
    ''' Create a new application '''
    user = request.user
    # check permission

    if request.method == 'POST':
        appform = AppForm(request.POST, prefix='app')

        if appform.is_valid():
            app = appform.save(commit=False)
            rolesInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Application, Role)
            # pdb.set_trace()
            rolesFormSet = rolesInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=app, prefix='roles')
            if rolesFormSet.is_valid():
                rolesFormSet.save()
            else:
                print rolesFormSet.errors
            app = appform.save()
            # check rolesFormSet

            return redirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        appform = AppForm(prefix='app')
        rolesFormSet = buildRolesFormset(Application)

    return render(request, 'who/editapp.html',
        {'appform': appform,
         'rolesFormSet': rolesFormSet
         })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky to tell without more information, but it looks like you're not saving your rolesFormset in the view. You need to call `rolesFormset.save()` alongside your `form.save()` call. Additionally, I suppose you want to attach the roles to the created app? Something like this in your view should work:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AppForm(request.POST)
    rolesFormset = RoleForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and rolesFormset.is_valid():
        app = form.save()
        roles = rolesFormset.save()
        for role in roles:
            app.roles.add(role)
        return redirect(reverse('index'))
```

**Update:** Presuming the models.py is out-of-date, and Role does in fact have a foreignKey to User, the problem will be that you're setting a prefix here:

```
rolesFormSet = rolesInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=app, prefix='roles')
```

but not in your `buildRolesFormset` function. In that function, do:

```
formset = RoleFormSet(prefix='roles')
```

Comment: my rolesFormSet is not clearing the is_valid and I have no idea why.  It seems that none of the fields are populated, although when I pring rolesFormSet.data in pdb I get `<QueryDict: {u'roles-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], u'roles-1-role_type': [u'4'], u'roles-0-user': [u'1'], u'app-owner': [u'1'], u'app-name': [u'1234'], u'app-serviceTier': [u''], u'app-jiraProject': [u''], u'roles-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2'], u'roles-1-user': [u''], u'roles-0-role_type': [u'3'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'eGsDwtswCKX0I9yUUcbKHlM3G3SQJfl0'], u'roles-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'2']}>`

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not saving, and it's also confusing why the 'app'-prefixed information is there.  FWIW, printing the POST request gives me the exact same output.

Comment: You should be able to see why the formset isn't valid by doing `print rolesFormset.errors` in the view.

Comment: I did-- it's telling me all the fields are empty and required.  IT LIES

Comment: What does `buildRolesFormset` do?

Comment: Makes me weep.  I added it above.  Only certain role_types apply to a given category, so this (theoretically) gets them and sets them as the values of role_type for each form.

Comment: Also updated the main function as it's undergone a day of changes.  Not that it works any better.

Comment: That can't be right, your models aren't linked by a foreignKey, and `inlineformset_factory` requires that. Have your models changed as well? (Update: see addition to answer)

Comment: They haven't changed, but I didn't include everything the first go as I was trying to be concise.  Updated with other relevant models.  I definitely am confused about the relationships between formsets an inlineformsets and have gone back and forth so many times that I'm certain the code is jumbled.